# Conflict FOREACH MySql SELECT PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How to fix conflict in foreach mysql PDO
I Try use other looping function but no give result, like while.this my script

the mysql PDO query, like this:

```
<?php
function calldata($table){
$db = dbConn::getConnection();

$sql = "select * from ".$table."" or die(mysql_error());
$q = $db->query($sql) or die("failed!");
while($res = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $record = array_map('stripslashes', $res);
            $db->records[] = $record; 
        }
        return $db->records;;
    //else echo "No records found";
  } 
 ?>
```

and to display the result, like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Category</td><td>
<select>
<option value="0">- select -</option>
<?php
        try{
        $db = dbConn::getConnection();
        $table='str_prod_category';
        $recordscat = calldata($table);
        if(count($recordscat)){ 
         foreach($recordscat as $key1=>$Recordcat){
        ?>
        <option value="<?=$Recordcat['id_category'];?>"><?=$Recordcat['cat_name'];?></option>
        <?php }}}catch (PDOException $e) {
//Output error - would normally log this to error file rather than output to user.
echo "Connection Error " . $e->getMessage();
} ?>
</select>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Brand</td><td>
<select>
<option value="0">- Select -</option>
<?php   try{
        $db = dbConn::getConnection();
        $table1='str_prod_brand';
        $recordsbrand = calldata($table1);
        if(count($recordsbrand)){
         foreach($recordsbrand as $key2=>$Recordbrand){
        ?>
        <option value="<?=$Recordbrand['id_brand'];?>"><?=$Recordbrand['brand_name'];?></option>
        <?php }}}catch (PDOException $e) {
//Output error - would normally log this to error file rather than output to user.
echo "Connection Error " . $e->getMessage();
} ?>
</select>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

this code is work and dislpay the data but for the option select brand, There is an empty selection, and then the right data after the empty data.

how to fix this?i have tried change the loop from foreach to while but no give result.

thanks

Comment: `mysql_error()` doesn't belong there. and the method name you declared is `calldata()`, but using `getRecords()` in presentation.

Comment: oh sory i miss that, in real code is "calldata()" i edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i try to use fillter using if and it's work to remove the blank recode

```
foreach($recordsbrand as $key2=>$Recordbrand){
if($Recordbrand['brand_name'] == ''){}else{
<option value="<?=$Recordbrand['id_brand'];?>"><?=$Recordbrand['brand_name'];?></option>
}}
```

but, i don't know is good or bad.